# What should a chazan do if he has theological problems with the congregation's text?

Tags: tefilla, selichot, chazzan-prayer-leader, theology, yom-kippur

There are several places in the selichot where there are controversial phrases, e.g. addressing prayer to angels not G-d.  I'm not asking for opinions on this, but I've heard some people just skip those lines.  What do you do if you normally skip the lines, but are now chazan?  How much license do you have to say "I just follow the congregation"?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7578 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30344

Answer (score 7):

If you normally skip something which the Congregation says, either you should not be the Chazan or if you are the Chazan "Al Tifrosh Min HaZibur".

Comment: That was my impression; anyone have any sources or other material on this?

Answer (score 4):

[R. Chaim Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Berlin) writes in a responsum (Nishmas Chaim # 7 in the one volume edition) that it is forbidden to publicly deviate from the nusach and the customs of the congregation, and it is a violation of Lo Sisgodedu.

> ולהתפלל בבית הכנסת של החסידים אין שום חשש בזה וגזירת רבינו הגר"א ז"ל
>   לא הי' אלא בזמנו שהקילו אז בכבוד תלמידי חכמים לומדי תורה ולא כן בימינו
>   שהחסידים חולקים כבוד לכל לומדי תורה והם יראי ה' ושומרים תורה ומצוה אך
>   על דבר שינוי נוסחת התפלה אסור לשנות בפרהסיא ממנהגיהם ומנוסחאותיהם
>   ובנוסח הקדושה יאמר קדושת כתר בשביל שנאמרת בקול רם ויש בזה איסור לא
>   תתגודדו וגם שלא לעורר מחלוקת ח"ו אבל בתפלה בלחש לא ישנה כבודו ממנהג
>   אבותיו וממנהגו מעולם ויתפלל שמונה עשרה בלחש כנוסח אשכנז

[R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) writes in a responsum ([O.C. 2:104](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=294&hilite=)) that one has to conform to the congregation's nusach for everything that can be said aloud (i.e. even if you are praying to yourself you have to use the congregation's nusach because you are saying something that could theoretically be said aloud).

> הנה בדבר מה נקרא דברים שבקול רם שצריך להתפלל בנוסח שמתפללים הצבור
>   במקום שמתפלל פשוט לע"ד שכל הדברים לבד תפלת י"ח צריך להתפלל בנוסח הצבור
>   ולא לסמוך על מה שיזהר לומר בלחש חדא דכיון שמותר לומר בקול רם קשה ליזהר
>   בזה ועוד דהא טוב יותר לומר כל מה שאפשר בקול רם כדי לעורר הכוונה
>   וכשיזהר לומר דוקא בלחש ידעו מזה גופיה שמתפלל בנוסח אחר

Moreover, in another responsum ([O.C. 2:94](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=287&hilite=)) about one who does not say Hallel on Passover Eve but is in a synagogue where they do say it, he must say it along with them and he is not even permitted to walk out. He also specifically mentions that if he is the chazan he must even make a beracha:

> הנוהגים בשיטת הגר"א אומרים הלל בביהכ"נ בלילי פסחים ולכן אף שביהכ"נ הוא
>   של נוסח אשכנז אומרים הלל שמסתמא היו שם מהבע"ב שנוהגין כהגר"א וממילא
>   אסור לשנות לומר להם שלא יאמרו וכן אסור ממילא לצאת דכיון שנהגו כן שם גם
>   מי שאינו נוהג לומר הלל כיון שעתה מתפלל בביהכ"נ זה אסור לשנות מפני
>   המחלוקת ואם יצא בשביל זה הרי נמי איכא טעם דאסור מפני המחלוקת כיון שהכל
>   יבינו שיצא משום שחולק עליהם אבל אין לו לברך כי זהו בצנעא דלא ניכר כ"כ
>   אם מברך או לא ואם היה באופן שיהיה ניכר שלא בירך נראה שצריך גם לברך
>   וראיה מפסחים דף ק"ו באמרו לו לר' אשי ליקדיש לן מר קידושא רבה אמר בפה"ג
>   ואגיד ביה ופי' רשב"ם האריך בו לדעת אם יסרהב אחד מהם לשתות יבין דבפה"ג
>   רגילין לומר ותו לא שאל"כ היה אומר להם קידוש גדול של לילה כמנהגם הרי
>   מפורש שאף שמנהגו שלא לקדש קידוש הלילה ביום מ"מ כיון שבעיר ההוא היו
>   נוהגין לקדש היה מקדש ולא היה חושש לברכה לבטלה א"כ כ"ש בהלל דלילי פסחים
>   שאיתא זה בירושלמי ובמס' סופרים שהביאו התוס' פסחים דף ק"ד והטור ס"ס
>   תע"ג כתב מה טוב ומה נעים ההיא מנהגא והמחבר פסק כן שודאי אין להחשיב זה
>   במקום שנהגו כמותם כספק ברכה לאסור אף לאלו שאין נוהגין כן אם נמצאו שם
>   ולכן אם הוא הש"צ צריך גם לברך וכן אף אם אינו ש"צ אם הוא באופן שיהיה
>   ניכר צריך לברך

(I know that these responsa don't discuss the precise case you are asking about.)

Comment: I just saw in Maaseh Rav that the Gra wouldn't say Veshamru in shul even though everyone else would. Does that contradict your sources?

Comment: @robev Not necessarily. The Chasam Sofer also didn't say Machnisei Rachamim (when the shul did).

Comment: Yeah but I heard he pretended to do a long tachanun, so no one noticed. People noticed the Gra

Comment: @robev He may have used a similar trick, or it may be different as a private individual, or depending on what the nature of the prayer is.

Comment: @robev I would like to note that many do not agree with R' Feinstein's ruling, and just say that you should not publicly deviate from the local minhag (e.g. saying davke Veshameru aloud in a Gra schul).

Comment: The Chazan should discuss the issue with the Rav in case it would be a good idea to change the nusach of the shul.

(I found myself in this situation and **after saying the nusach of the shul the first time** (following Gershon Gold above) I suggested a different nusach to the Rav which he accepted.)