# Answering kedusha differently to the kehilla?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, tzibur-community, nuschaot, kedusha-prayer

If one is praying a nusach which is different to the nusach that the shul is using, is it wrong to answer according to your own nusach?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30344/759

Comment: The only parts of Kedusha that the congregation needs to say are ubiquitous among all Nuschaot. (OC 125)

Comment: The scope of Kedusha is that everybody says the same thing together. If you say somewhat else, you are not with the Tsibur.

Comment: @kouty You'd still be answering with the tzibur just saying something slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other practices out there, and it's confusing to learn the responses of another nusach, but Rav Moshe Feinstein's position was that anything communal and out-loud -- including the kedusha response -- should follow the kehilla's nusach.

Comment: please references