Minhaguim for a convert how to make the best choice advices
I know that a convert can choose his minhag as whatever he wants. But how to make the best choice according to the Torah logic?
As the convert is considered as a newborn, which minhag should he follow?

his sponsoring rabbi conversion (as he became a newborn through his contribution)

his post-conversion rabbi (as all halachic links before his conversion are revoked)

his father (when he is Jewish, as his link with Jewish history and self-identity but not related halachically)


Thank you

I know that he can chose whatever he wants. But how to make the best choice according the Torah logic?

I don't think that best choice exists, but it is practical to stick to the customs of the synagogue you attended while converting.

Thank you for your answer. So there is no logical for a ger who is Zera Israel to take minhaguim from his father ? (Actually is the category Zera Israel based on halakha or on just socio-cultural approach?)

ps: I read that Zera Israel only applies to a child under 13 whose father is Jewish and who wants to convert him

One may do so, as it is written in the linked answers, but definitely CYLOR.

OK thank you and Goods advices. If he moves later or daven in others shul, should he keep the original minhag (of the synagogue he attended while converting) as he is a newborn I thought that his past is no relevant so is this apply even during the period while converting before mikve?

Once someone has finished the conversion, it does not matter anymore. Then the question arises whether one should stick to her/his original customs when moving to another place or not. There are a lot of questions in the matter on MY.

Can you send  links for this questions on MY.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30347/15256
